# Move Azure SQL Data to existing excel file in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, powerapps

I have an app in Powerapps which uses Azure SQL database.

I want to download data from SQL via my App, and dump it into an existing excel file in Azure Blob Storage.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, please can you advise what software I need to learn to make this work.

(Please note: I do not want to use the power automate method of using ‘add rows to excel table’ hosted in onedrive or Sharepoint)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Yes this can very well be achieved
- you already mentioned the technologies you wish to work with and with those technologies it is possible.
- First create a canvas app (powerapps)
- In the app connect to azure sql database (out of the box connector) provided by microsot.
- create a gallery and show table and it's column.
  -create a button to download data as csv/excel.
- perfrom on select operation on your button.
- you might have to learn and understand few things but it should not be difficult.